# can't connect to OpenLDAP server in EC2 instance (AWS)

Tags: linux, security, amazon-ec2, openldap, security-groups

I would like to know if exist some additional security measures from AWS while connect to a OpenLDAP server in EC2 Linux instance (Ubuntu 18.04).

I need this OpenLDAP server to check if user/password combinations are ok in a spring App with login services.

So firts i've installed the OpenLDAP in linux as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mR-7SXX4wVo. Then i've used Apache Directory Studio to check if the connection was ok but this propmts a connection timeout.

Finally I've been researching for some limitations or security measures in the EC2 instance to connect to the LDAP and found this post https://www.turnkeylinux.org/comment/38038#comment-38038 leading me to check the AWS Security Group to add the LDAP port 389 as recommended (not 636 because is not LDAPS) and also used `netstat -tlnp` to check if the connection was listening in the EC2 instance and shows that is listening on port 389 (so it's ok).

So now I'm stuck because I don't know what else I can do to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this post https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/ where you can see two limitations, one is the Security group rules and the other one is the network ACL. I've already done the config for the Security groups but not done for ACL so i did it and after a reboot of the EC2 instances it works well. Hope it helps someone else.